# Random misplacement of a div

Tags: javascript, css

I'm making a website for myself and it has a projects page and I made a js script to auto add each of the projects using a json file. I have 4 projects in the json file so far but one of them is acting up. [image: Image here]

Circled in red is the div that is messed up.
Here is the css for those divs:

```
#img {
vertical-align: top;
display: inline-block;
border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px;
width: 340px;
}
#title {
    margin-top: 40px;
    vertical-align: top;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 30px;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
}
#desc {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Now here is the js script that is adding them:

```
$.getJSON('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Pinball3D/andysthings/main/registy.json', 
function(data){
  console.log(data);
  var i = 0;
  console.log(data.length, i < data.length)
  while (i < data.length) {
    dat = data[i];
    var a = document.createElement("a");
    a.href=dat.url;
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.id="item";
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src=dat.img;
    img.id="img";
    li.appendChild(img);
    var title = document.createElement("div");
    title.id="title";
    title.textContent=dat.name;
    li.appendChild(title);
    var desc = document.createElement("div");
    desc.id="desc";
    desc.textContent=dat.desc;
    li.appendChild(desc);
    a.appendChild(li);
    document.querySelector("#grid").appendChild(a);
    i++;
  }
});
```

I don't know what is causing that element to be out of place.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for that is `float: left;` and `display: inline-block;` on the title and description.

The purpose of `float` is to make text float around an element if there is enough space (like an image or drop caps)

Based on the image it is not clear why you use `display: inline-block;` and `float` at all. As it seems that the description should always be below the title.

So remove `float: left` and change `inline-block` to `block` for both title and description.

Nowadays `float` should only be used if you really need to let float text around and element and not for other layout purposes. For layouts where `float` was used you should use `flex` or `grid` instead.

Additional having `a` as a child of `ul` is not valid. And a `li` as a child of `a` isn't either.

```js
$.getJSON('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Pinball3D/andysthings/main/registy.json',
  function(data) {
    //console.log(data);
    var i = 0;
    //console.log(data.length, i < data.length)
    while (i < data.length) {
      dat = data[i];
      var li = document.createElement("li");
      li.id = "item";
      
      var a = document.createElement("a");
      a.href = dat.url;
      
      var img = document.createElement("img");
      img.src = dat.img;
      img.id = "img";
      a.appendChild(img);
      var title = document.createElement("div");
      title.id = "title";
      title.textContent = dat.name;
      a.appendChild(title);
      var desc = document.createElement("div");
      desc.id = "desc";
      desc.textContent = dat.desc;
      a.appendChild(desc);
      
      li.appendChild(a);
      document.querySelector("#grid").appendChild(li);
      i++;
    }
  });
```

```css
body {
 font-family: sans-serif;
}
#img {
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px;
  width: 340px;
}

#title {
  margin-top: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 30px;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

#desc {
  margin-left: 5px;
}

#grid {
   display: flex;
   flex-flow: row wrap;
   justify-content: space-between;
}


#grid li {
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: rgb(200,200,200);
    max-width: 340px;
    color: white;
}

#grid li a {
   display: block;
   color: inherit;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="grid">
</ul>
```

Comment: This is what happened: https://imgur.com/a/gKZ9zfo

Comment: @Andrew Well I don't know what the other relevant styles look like. Looks you use `float` for your `li` and some do some other stuff that messes the layout up.

Comment: @Andrew added a code snippet and added some basic styling and it shows that this works. So you have some other stylings on the page that make it break. Looks like you have more `float` applied, and likely other things you should not do.

Comment: huh I don't know. In dev-tools when i delete the element, the one that was next didn't have the same issue

Comment: @Andrew yes that's due to the `float` you use for layout. `float` results in many problems like that. **Don't use `float` for layout**